# Generating Dates in Alteryx

Tags: initialization, expression, rows, generate, alteryx

Is there a way that I can generate dates between a Start and an End Date by using a RecordID as the Initialization Expression? The reason is because some of my data has duplicates whether that be the date or a different part of the data and I want to still generate dates to fill in between them whether part of it is duplicate or not. If I use the starting date for each record than it leaves some of the records out after generating because of duplicate information. But if I could use the recordID which is unique to each one than it would include all of the records.

Answer (score 0):

First, isolate your desired start and end dates, for instance use the [Summarize](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/summarize-tool) Tool to generate `minDate` as `min([yourDateField])` and `maxDate` as `max([yourDateField])`.

Then send those into a [Generate Rows](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/generate-rows-tool) tool. In that tool, specify that you're creating a new variable, let's call it `[newDate]`. For Initialization Expression, simply specify `[minDate]`, for Condition Expression, specify `[newDate. <= [maxDate]`, and for Loop Expression, specify `DateTimeAdd([newDate],1,'days')` ... the output from that tool will be all the days (as rows) from minDate to maxDate.

Then [Join](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/join-tool) that back to your main data on the `newDate = yourDateField` ... and finally, [Union](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/union-tool) the outputs of the Join tool together to end up with empty rows with the new dates intermixed with populated rows of your original data.